# Fastest way to resolve 100 million A-records in Python

Tags: python, dns, performance

I have a list with 100 million domain names like www.microsoft.com and would like to resolve the IP-number to www.microsoft.com

Running a local pdns server and query localhost using Python adns?

Comment: That will take a while! And, after you're done many of the IPs will have changed (so your resolved IPs will be incorrect). What are you trying to do?

Comment: I don't see the point of running a local DNS server, since it won't magically know any of the addresses anyway. Given that each DNS lookup is going to take you at least 10 milliseconds or so, it'll be over three months before your list is converted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd probably use [Twisted DNS](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.names.html) libray to do the DNS resolution from [Google's Public DNS](http://code.google.com/speed/public-dns/docs/using.html) (ip address: 8.8.8.8). It'd take some trial and error but I'd guess you could have at least a couple hundred outstanding queries going at once. Google's DNS infrastructure is designed to handle a huge load and Twisted is well suited to handling thousands of simultaneous asychronous operations.

Comment: ... but trying to cram 100 million queries through any server at a high rate is likely to get your IP blacklisted and your ISP sent a nasty note.

Comment: Ordinarily I'd agree with you but in this particular case if you were to call Google and ask for permission, I'll bet they'd say "Bring it!". Their DNS architecture is designed to handle extreme loads. A single machine pinging away as fast as it can won't make a dent.

Answer (score 2):

I actually had to solve this particular problem quite recently. All public servers I found where quite limited, and answered at a rate of around 2000 qps (queries per second). 2000 qps is clearly too low for millions of FQDNs.

I ended up configuring a recursive resolver to do this in a reasonable amount of time. Use the recursive resolver of you choice. Below I give an example of using unbound.

**Using unbound**

`unbound` should be part of most modern distros, and also available at their [their page](https://nlnetlabs.nl/projects/unbound/about/). Using the following configuration, optimized for 12 threaded server without fully killing it, I was able to go way above 2 000 qps, peaking at around 100 000 qps.

```
# /etc/unbound/unbound.conf
server:
        verbosity: 1
        num-threads: 10
        outgoing-range: 32768
        msg-cache-size: 400m
        msg-cache-slabs: 8
        num-queries-per-thread: 8192
        unknown-server-time-limit: 150
        rrset-cache-size: 400m
        rrset-cache-slabs: 8
        infra-cache-slabs: 8
        infra-cache-numhosts: 1000000
        trust-anchor-file: /etc/unbound/trusted-key.key
        key-cache-size: 400m
        key-cache-slabs: 8
        neg-cache-size: 100m
```

**Testing your recursive resolver**

After you have configured your recursive resolver of choice it might be worth it to test it. [This dns-stresstester works well for me.](https://github.com/MickaelBergem/dnsstresss) You can try the following:

```
go get github.com/MickaelBergem/dnsstresss
cd ~/go/bin
./dnsstresss -random -concurrency 400 google.com.
```

This gives me:

```
dnsstresss - dns stress tool

Testing resolver: 127.0.0.1:53.
Target domains: [google.com.].

Started 400 threads.
Requests sent: 110445r/s        Replies received: 110445r/s (mean=3ms / max=70ms)
Requests sent: 113971r/s        Replies received: 113971r/s (mean=3ms / max=108ms)
Requests sent:  93589r/s        Replies received:  93589r/s (mean=4ms / max=111ms)
Requests sent:  93986r/s        Replies received:  93986r/s (mean=4ms / max=202ms)
Requests sent: 102510r/s        Replies received: 102510r/s (mean=4ms / max=75ms)
```